# Ignore `is_active` filed for custom user model

Tags: python, django, django-3.1

I'm trying to make custom user model, when instead of few boolean columns, I will manage user permissions based on one `status` filed:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _


class MyUser(AbstractUser):
    username = None
    is_staff = None
    is_superuser = None
    is_active = None
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
    status = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0)
```

In `settings.py` file added:

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ['django.contrib.auth.backends.AllowAllUsersModelBackend']
```

Then, when trying to login, getting error: `This account is inactive.`

How to ignore `is_active` filed for my custom user model ?

Comment: Are you trying to login in django admin ?

Comment: @Amin - No. I don't use django admin in this case

Comment: @Amin: the exception is likely raised by the `AuthenticationForm`: https://github.com/django/django/blob/536c155e67fd82ef23975919bd55ccec966f96f8/django/contrib/auth/forms.py#L224-L228

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace `is_active` with a property, so:

```
class MyUser(AbstractUser):
    # …
    # no is_active field
    # …
    @property
    def is_active(self):
        return self.status > 0
```

Comment: Yes but in this case `is_active` column will keep in users table. I'm trying to manage user permissions by `status` column only.

Comment: @OtoShavadze: so exactly when is the user active based on the `status` field?

Comment: when status will be more than 0

Comment: @OtoShavadze: then you can make it a property.

Comment: @OtoShavadze: can you please [edit the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68710131/edit) since now the question is missing essential data.

Answer (score 0):

As docs says in https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.has_perm:

> You can use AllowAllUsersModelBackend or AllowAllUsersRemoteUserBackend if you want to allow inactive users to login. In this case, you’ll also want to customize the AuthenticationForm used by the LoginView as it rejects inactive users. Be aware that the permission-checking methods such as has_perm() and the authentication in the Django admin all return False for inactive users.

So you have to override `has_perm()` method to ignore `is_active()`